# Joomla multisite

Tags: joomla, web

My client needed a few requirements in Joomla 2.5, not sure these changes can be done in Joomla 2.5

Using "Moset Tree" component they are creating categories and within the categories it has 1000's of users list.

Now the client required, each user in the list will have separate site like - `www.mysite.com/user1` `www.mysite.com/user2` each user will have templates, few pages and the pages can be managed from user end.

I am new Moset Tree and I go through the admin panel of the site and it has options for - "Listing Template" and "Custom URL" but not sure about the use of these options. I do not have permission to check these options in the admin panel. Please suggest, Is this options can ful fill my requirement?

Also right now the site is Joomla 1.5 and it will be upgraded to Joomla2.5 with Moset Tree component upgrade.

Please let me know, If there any other components are available in Joomla3.0 for multi site. I go through the [JMS2win](http://tutorial.jms2win.com/joomla/multisite-12x/joomla-subsite-overview/) component, it has different database for different user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think one issue causing you difficulty is considering www.mysite.com/user2 a site. These would just be pages within the main site. You don't need multi-site capability for that.